# Attempting to plot dataframe with specific rows as the lines and the columns as the xticks

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to plot a line graph that shows multiple lines within my dataframe as the separate lines for comparison i.e. having one as the 'expected' and another to show variations. Additionally, I'm trying to show the columns as the xticks and percentages as the y values:

[image: Screenshot of table]

What I'm trying to show is row 1 as the 'expected' percent and then be able to use any other row i.e. food, bakery products, etc. to show any deviation for that across all columns (serving as the x-axis). I hope that this make sense and any help is appreciated!! I'm a new coder going through a bootcamp.